# Data Migration Error related to CREATE TRIGGER

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, data-migration, mysql-triggers

i'm getting the error when i try to run data step for the data migration tool. The extension "codisto" has been uninstalled while ago. Please advise

```
[Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for th
  e right syntax to use near ';
  /* end codisto change tracking trigger */
  END;
  INSERT INTO m2_cl_cataloginvent' at line 4, query was: CREATE TRIGGER codisto_cataloginventory_stock_item_update AFTER UPDATE ON cataloginventory_stock_item FOR EA
  CH ROW
  BEGIN
  /* start codisto change tracking trigger */
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'codisto_product_change') THEN INSERT INTO `codisto_product_change` SET product_id = NEW.produ
  ct_id, stamp = UTC_TIMESTAMP() ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_id = product_id, stamp = UTC_TIMESTAMP(); IF;
  /* end codisto change tracking trigger */
  END;
  INSERT INTO m2_cl_cataloginventory_stock_item (`item_id`, `operation`) VALUES (NEW.item_id, 'UPDATE')ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE operation = 'UPDATE';
  END

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for th

  e right syntax to use near ';
  /* end codisto change tracking trigger */
  END;
  INSERT INTO m2_cl_cataloginvent' at line 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received the responded from Codisto. They provided the following script to fully cleanup the left over data from the extension. https://github.com/CodistoConnect/CodistoConnect-Shell